# MySQL fixed ids for categories, how to ensure they are static

Tags: mysql, database

I have a system that has categories that are joined to events. All of these categories are simple, they have an id, and name. One thing that worries me is that when I am creating these categories, the ids should always remain the same, be static. If I deleted one, let's say "Politics" at id=1, all of those events would have an orphaned category. One solution I thought of is to just assign string ids to them, so if they do happen to get deleted, it wouldn't really matter. What kind of solution do you recommend?

From my perspective it seems like you could keep the ids and just put a constraint that doesn't allow you to delete the record, only edit them. Another, is to use string ids, but that seems like a pain, although it seems to solve the problem of worrying about the ids being messed with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is what foreign key constraints are for.  They also allow for rules on how to handle deletes -- for example, allowing a delete to cascade through dependent records, which is of course very dangerous and not what you would want in this situation.  A simple basic constraint will do.

HOWEVER!!!! This is the important thing to understand about mysql.  The default mysql engine (myisam) has absolutely no support for foreign key constraints.  You need to use an engine that supports them -- most commonly innodb.

If you specify a constraint when you're generating your DDL, a myisam table will accept the constraint but simply ignore it, so make sure all your related tables are setup/altered to be innodb tables before you add your constraint(s).

How do you add a constraint?

```
ALTER TABLE `event` ADD CONSTRAINT `category_event` 
FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`category_id`);
```

In this example, it assumes your event table has the foreign key category_id in it, to create your linkage.  After adding this constraint, if you attempt to delete a row from the category table, and an existing event row contains that key, mysql will disallow the DELETE and return an error.  This is discussed in great detail here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html